# eclipse console window strange output when running c program

Tags: c, eclipse, console, eclipse-cdt

I have a simple c program:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main() {
    int k, r;
    long int i = 0l, j = 1, f;

    printf("FIBONACCI SERIES:\n");

    // Taking maximum numbers from user
    printf("Enter the number range:");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    // Printing first two values.
    printf("\n%ld %ld", i, j);

    for (k = 2; k < r; k++) {
        f = i + j;
        i = j;
        j = f;
        printf(" %ld", j);
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

when i run it in eclipse c/c++ console i must first input a number (scanf), after that the desired output is displayed. The first output should be:

printf("FIBONACCI SERIES:\n");

But is does not. I must input a number first. Then the rest follows:

```
--------------------------
8
FIBONACCI SERIES:
Enter the number range:
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
--------------------------
```

When i run the excutable file in a cmd window, it works as wanted...

```
FIBONACCI SERIES:
Enter the number range:8

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
```

(Just started with Eclipse). Thank you.

Changed to:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int k, r;
long int i = 0l, j = 1, f;

printf("FIBONACCI SERIES:\n");

// Taking maximum numbers from user
printf("Enter the number range:\n");
scanf("%d", &r);

// Printing first two values.
printf("\n%ld %ld", i, j);

for (k = 2; k < r; k++) {
    f = i + j;
    i = j;
    j = f;
    printf(" %ld", j);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Same result:

```
-------------------------------
8
FIBONACCI SERIES:
Enter the number range:

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
-------------------------------
```

Comment: What happens if you put a `newline` at the end of the prompt like `printf("Enter the number range:\n");`? There should be a final `newline` after the series is printed too, really.

Comment: There is a known bug with eclipse console output which is hanging there for several years now...

Comment: Thanks a **lot**. I will live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing here is down to buffering. When you run a program in the Eclipse console you are operating with a pipe and the standard library will buffer with that. However when you run from a terminal you get tty buffering. By default in pipe buffering `stdout` will be fully buffered, but in a terminal it will be line buffered.

You can resolve this by simply flushing the buffer, e.g.

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf` / before the `scanf`

Alternatively you can force the buffering with `setbuf`.

Here is the key bit from [man setbuf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

> Normally all files are block buffered.  If a stream refers to a
>   terminal (as stdout normally does), it is line buffered.  The
>   standard error stream stderr is always unbuffered by default.

Final thing to note, you should be able to reproduce the problem in a terminal by running your program through `tee`:

```
$ ./fib_from_so 
FIBONACCI SERIES:
Enter the number range:8

0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13

$ ./fib_from_so | tee output
8
FIBONACCI SERIES:
Enter the number range:
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
```